# Unit Testing HTTP Post request with database access

Tags: node.js, sqlite, unit-testing, chai, chai-http

Hi I'm currently trying to learn and implement some unit testing for my HTTP Requests. currently I have a SQlite db setup, and a simple post request. This is the test I have written so far:

```
"use strict";
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

const app = require('../../../app');

chai.request('http://localhost:8080')
    .put('/tempValue')
    .send({sensorid: '1', sensorValue: '25.00', timeRecorded: '2020-04-12 12:30'})
    .then(function (res) {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        throw err;
    });
```

I seem to be getting a error that it is unable to open the database file. Currently I am just connecting to the database in the app.js file, using `const dbPath = "./database/database.db";` and  `const dbConnection = sqlite.open(dbPath, { Promise });`

I also seem to get errors about incorrect use of .catch? This is the error log:

```
(node:13952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
(node:13952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unha
ndled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13952) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 404
    at D:\Uni Work\3rd Year\302CEM - Agile Development\Penguin Project\test\api\temperature\get.js:15:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:13952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unha
ndled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

This is the particular post request I'm testing, it uses MQTT to check if the message being sent is to that topic structure, then inserts into the database.

```
app.ws.use(route.all('/tempValue', function (ctx){
    client.on('message', async function(topic,message){
        console.log(topic, message.toString());
        if (topic === '302CEM/Penguin/Room1/Temperature'){
            const SQL = "INSERT INTO sensorData (sensorid, sensorValue, timeRecorded) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            try {
                const temptostring = message.toString();
                const db = await dbConnection;
                await db.run(SQL, ["1",temptostring, moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')]);
                ctx.websocket.send(temptostring);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    })
}));
```

Comment: The code you showed us is your test code -- your mock client for your HTTP requests. But it looks like the fault you showed is in your server. Please [edit] your question to show us your server code, and we may be able to help you a bit better.

Comment: @O.Jones I have included the particular function im trying to test from app.js. This post request is using websockets and MQTT.